# WORKDAY.INTL not skipping holidays

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, formula

There's clearly a mistake that I've made that I can't seem to fix. I'm making a table to outline dates for product information (as per screenshot)

[image: Table 1]
[image: Holidays]

My current formula im working with is

```
=TEXT(WORKDAY.INTL(C4,1,1,M:M),"mmm dd") & "-"&TEXT(WORKDAY.INTL(C4,10,1,M:M),"mmm dd")
```

The value in C4 is Feb 28, so this is displaying
Mar 01 - Mar 14

So the first 1 is adding 1 day to the first date, and the second adding 10 to make a range.

The 2nd 1 in workday.intl is to set Saturday+Sunday as the weekends, and then M:M to take a list of all holidays in that column.

No matter what I do, I can add in 50 holidays into column M and they don't seem to change the table. The format is simply MM dd yy so 1/1/24 is coming back as Monday, January 1, 2024. I also made a column N that is `=DATE(YEAR(M2) MONTH(M2)DAY(M2))` and it comes back with a value (45292) but the formula `=DATEVALUE(M2)` is throwing back #VALUE.

It has to be an issue with my holidays but I can't seem to figure out what's going on. I've messed with date formatting and also text to columns and changing to date, but nothing seems to work. Is the issue that DATEVALUE needs to be the value to use for holidays for WORKDAY.INTL?

I would just like to have the values all shifted in my table when a holidays falls between the range

Comment: If you change the formatting of Column C to `mmm dd yyyy`, does it say "Mar 28 202**4**", or "Mar 28 202**3**"?

Comment: Have you tried changing the format of column M to some other date format or a different format entirely? The way Excel handles that could give you a clue about what is wrong with the holiday dates.

Comment: To shows up as 2023? But that doesn't make sense, as C5 is pulling from C4+20 and C4 is C3+20, C3 is C2+20 and C2 is pulling from J1 which is titles START DATE which is 01/03/2024. How did it shift the years downwards? That would explain why it wasn't working lol. How do I shift it to 2024

Comment: So the cells I have are C2: Jan3, C3: Jan31, C4:Feb28 C2 is correct, it's 2024, then as soon as I add yyyy to C3, it says 2023. So the issue is the year shifting on other dates. But sure why it didn't retain 2024

Comment: There is a problem with your data, or the formula you are using to create it.  You need to show the actual contents of the various cells.  And one working day after `28-Feb-2024` would be `29-Feb-2024`, **not** `1-Mar-2024`

Answer (score 0):

Chronocidal asked me to check cell C3 by adding yyyy to the display, and every cell except for C2 is set to 2023.

So the holidays isn't the issue, it looks like the date changed in the year for the tables.

For some reason, it reversed and went to 2023 rather than retaining 2024 which makes no sense as everything else is built off of C2 + X.

Anyone know why excel randomly changes years and how to prevent this? It should, in theory, mantain the same year, and then incrementing the year after December. But is this because of the current calendar year in excel? And why it defaulted to 2023? Anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: I found a post that said to just +364 to the date (not a typo) and it will work. I did that and it seems okay. Looks a little gross and wish there was a better way but this will do. Unless someone else has a better way

Comment: This **answer** is not an answer to your problem and should not be posted as such. Rather it should be included in the comments to your question. And the solution you propose in your comment to this "answer" is not robust, and doesn't address your real issue. Please delete this Answer

Comment: If you type the date in using a short-form (i.e. "Jan 31" or "31/01") instead of a full-form (i.e. "Jan 31 2024" or "31/01/2024", or "2024-01-31") then Excel will automatically default to the **current year**.  (Conversely, if your short-form skips the day instead, e.g. "Jan 2024", then it will default to the 1st of the month).  As such, this seems likely to be a data-entry issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).